# Installation procedure changed?

Tags: google-drive-api

Since the apps scope has been moved from drive.app to drive.apps.readonly the installation procedure seems to have changed as well(?).

It used to work perfectly to grant access to drive *without* installing the app to drive.

Now when a user grants access the app is half-installed - which means it appears in the list of the users apps even though he did not install it from the webstore.

This is bad, because now there is no way to tell if the app is already installed.
When the app is half-installed the custom file icons do not appear in drive.

My app installation worked perfectly before the change - now it seems to be somehow broken.
Is there a recommended way right now how to update the drive integration to get the same seamless experience as before?

Answer (score 0):

As an explanation, we felt it would be important for users to be able to see all apps authorized to user their Drive, with a convenient way to revoke access. Your app is not half installed, it is installed, and once installed you can ask the user to authorize for files as you need.

I'm sorry this feels non-seamless to you right now, and we are looking to improve this experience for you, so stay tuned. I will update this answer when that happens.

Comment: First of all: I'm really impressed by the Drive / Picker API and it takes the whole internet OS stuff to the next level.


That being said: In my use case it looks really half-installed as the user can see the app in the installed apps on Google Drive but is not able to create new files of my app / gets no custom file icons.

Comment: I've been thinking about this issue for some more time... I think it would be great to only do the automatic installation when requesting the drive.apps scope. As we now the the drive.apps.readonly scope this would make perfect sense. As a user it may be confusing that apps get added to drive without granting access to the drive apps. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, agreed that is the right direction for the solution. As I say, stay tuned.